# If $q \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, then for $a \in ]-1,1[$ is $q < \frac{1}{a}$?

Tags: inequality

If $q \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, then for $a \in ]-1,1[$ is $$q < \frac{1}{a}$$

s.t.

$$a < \frac{1}{q}$$

The slight problem I see in this is that since $a$ can be positive or negative, then is the final inequality right? Since one switches it if one multiplies the first inequality by negative $a$. But not if one multiplies by positive $a$.

Do I need to take an absolute value somewhere? Because $a$ can take both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Obviously this can't be true for every value of $a$.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Should I maybe consider taking $q < \frac{1}{|a|}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property your question is not clear, see also http://planetmath.org/archimedeanproperty